# How to add class inside canvas object jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, css

I work with canvas, and i have issues, i want to create layout with canvas objects. But i want to create object in css, and create in HTML.

For now i create:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

context.beginPath();


context.rect(10, 50, 200, 100);
context.fillStyle = 'red';
context.fill();
context.fillStyle = 'black';
context.font = '20px Courier';
context.shadowColor = 'transparent';
context.shadowBlur = 0;
context.shadowOffsetX = 0;
context.shadowOffsetY = 0;
context.fillText(`List item`, 70, 80);
context.fillText(`List item2`, 70, 130);

var image = new Image();
image.src = "https://pngimage.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/machine-icon-png-9.png";
image.onload = function () {
    context.drawImage(image, 10, 70, 50, 50);
};
```

CSS:

```
.box-test {
    width: 150px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

HTML:

```
 <canvas id="myCanvas" width="1280" height="720"
            style="border:1px solid #c3c3c3;">
        Your browser does not support the canvas element.
    </canvas>
```

This code are build boxes with image and text, but color, image i want to get from CSS, somehow it's possible to create object in canvas use css styles?

As u can see i have class **box-test** and here i give properties to box:

```
context.rect(10, 50, 200, 100);
    context.fillStyle = 'red';
    context.fill();
```

Can i use only cordinates here, and **width, height, color** get from css?

Comment: Please use SVG if everything in your objective are definable shapes, not something like a video game

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29675279/how-to-style-canvas-elements-with-css

Comment: @DickensAS can u provide some example?

Comment: @xdeepakv this is only for color, but i want text and image also

Answer (score -1):

If you use SVG you can on the fly add elements to it

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("svgArea");
var rec = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg","rect")
rec.setAttributeNS(null, "class","box-test");
canvas.appendChild(rec);

var image = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg","image")
image.setAttributeNS(null, "href","https://pngimage.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/machine-icon-png-9.png");
image.setAttributeNS(null, 'height', '50');
image.setAttributeNS(null, 'width', '50');
image.setAttributeNS(null, 'x', 60);
image.setAttributeNS(null, 'y', 60); 
canvas.appendChild(image );

var text = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg","text");
text.textContent= "Hello World!";
text.setAttributeNS(null, 'x', 120);
text.setAttributeNS(null, 'y', 120); 
text.setAttributeNS(null, "class","text-style");
canvas.appendChild(text);
```

```css
.box-test {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
 x: 20px;
 y: 20px;
    fill:rgb(0,0,255);
    stroke-width:3;
    stroke:rgb(0,0,0);
}

.text-style {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: Courier;
}
```

```html
<svg id="svgArea" width="500" height="500"></svg>
```

To set `X` and `Y` coordinates then you can use this code

```
rec.setAttributeNS(null, 'x', x);
rec.setAttributeNS(null, 'y', y);
```

To set `width` and `height`

```
rec.setAttributeNS(null, 'height', '50');
rec.setAttributeNS(null, 'width', '50');
```

Comment: This is allready not good, because script will create canvas object from loop, and class i need to add inside js

Comment: you can create svg from loop without setting any css

Comment: @Andrew this code adds a rectangle dynamically with predefined CSS, you can use this technique without using canvas

Comment: yes, if you are grammatically decided to create the diagrams and also want to use CSS, then canvas is not your friend

Comment: But any way i need to have cordinates because it's wiil be layout

Comment: yes, you can pragmatically position and do whatever you did in canvas in SVG

Comment: @Andrew now this example has, text with font stye in CSS, image and rectangle :)