# CSS styles not applied to SVG when SVG is rendered on Canvas

Tags: html, css, svg, canvas, png

I am styling an SVG image using CSS in a separate file. Then I am rendering the SVG onto a canvas that can be saved as a PNG.

The SVG receives the CSS styles properly when it is just an SVG element on an HTML page, and renders as expected. However, when the SVG is rendered in a canvas element, the styles are not applied.

Is it possible to use external CSS to style an SVG and save that to a canvas without losing the styles? I cannot use inline CSS due to Content Security Policy in the browser.

Here is a sample.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>svg to png</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <button>svg to png</button>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="200" height="200">

    <path d="M10 40, C20 20, 50 20, 70 30, 70 30, 110 50, 160 20" id="path-1" fill="#CCCCCC" />

    <text class="text-red">
      <textpath xlink:href="#path-1" startOffset="50%" text-anchor="middle">Sample Path Text</textpath>
    </text>

    <rect x="10" y="14" width="10" height="10" />

    <text x="0" y="100" class="text-primary">Text Style 1</text>
    <text x="0" y="150" class="text-secondary">Text Style 2</text>
  </svg>

  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
  <script src="./script.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

**style.css**

```
.text-primary {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-family: calibri;
}

.text-secondary {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: arial;
}

.text-red {
  fill: #ff0000;
}
```

**script.js**

```
var btn = document.querySelector("button");
var svg = document.querySelector("svg");
var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");

btn.addEventListener("click", function () {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  var data = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svg);
  var DOMURL = window.URL || window.webkitURL || window;

  var img = new Image();
  var svgBlob = new Blob([data], { type: "image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8" });
  var url = DOMURL.createObjectURL(svgBlob);

  img.onload = function () {
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    DOMURL.revokeObjectURL(url);

    var imgURI = canvas
      .toDataURL("image/png")
      .replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");
  };

  img.src = url;
});
```

Here is a render of the basic example, svg on the left and canvas on the right.

[css styles applied to svg on left, css styles not applied to svg on canvas on right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9QlH2.png)

Comment: Where is it that you connect the styles to the SVG? There's no <style> element in the SVG file.

Comment: I think you'll have to write the styles direct into the SVG text elements. Or pick them up from the class and write them in at run time - does this help? [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29675279/how-to-style-canvas-elements-with-css

Comment: Are the stylesheets accessible as same-origin? With this CSP you'd have to fetch them as text and reinject them in the svg file as text too, which is dirty...