# CSS to override Google Sheets gridlines?

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-sheets, web-inspector, stylebot

I'm looking for help on why my CSS isn't working.

I want to use the **Stylebot chrome extension** with this CSS to make gridlines darker on a Google Sheet.

```
.waffle td, .grid-fixed-table td {
  border: 1px solid;
  border-color:  black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

The gridlines show for a second when loading a new sheet but then disappear. Can anyone help me to understand why/show me a solution?

Comment: The actual rendering of the sheet is done on a canvas element which wouldn't be affected by this CSS.

Comment: @DanCarter thanks. I figured something like that was going on, but I had reached my upper limits to understanding while poking around in Chrome dev tools.

Is there a way to style canvas elements? Or is the answer that it's not possible?

Comment: Unfortunately there's no way to style specific content within the canvas element itself. It's effectively just a drawing in there with no real HTML elements to target.

Comment: This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39081403/2817442